# IE7 not displaying div containing text correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having difficulty trying to get IE7 to behave like a normal browser.

I have a HTML sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/6QSYM/4/ that looks fine in most browsers, but when viewed with IE7 you can see that the "Sector Used" text is merged with the line below it.

Can somebody suggest how I can correct this?

Comment: it actually looks very similar to me in ff4 and ie7 (both pretty bad). Are you talking about the horizontal line overlapping?

Comment: It looks fine for me in Firefox 4. In IE 7 though, I see the horizontal line running through the "Sector Used" text.

Comment: Are any of the answers any good to you?  If not please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this problem all the time! At the company I work at we still have to support IE7 (will it ever just DIE!). So the best solution I have found is to set the width for your none floating div. It's a hassle but that why IE knows how to calculate the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
clear:both;
```

to your `.risk-statistic-container` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6QSYM/9/

the semantics of your HTML elements are all over the place as well.  Way too many spans and divs for me :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: the problem I have with this answer is that 1) semantically, the top section isn't a list, so I don't like using the `<ul>` structure, and 2) the "Sector being used" text is left-aligned. I need that to align to the right. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I guess if you were being strict about it.  They are a logically related grouping though so you could be flexible. In the grand scheme of things it's not that big of a deal. You'd be better off dropping the <br /> elements as well urgh...